# Unbearable TypeError: this.state.products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, woocommerce

I am trying to pull data from woocommerce in which this data gets put into an empty array and for each object in that array I will get a particular piece of data from it.

Here is my code:

```
export class MainRight extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const productsURL = "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wc/v2/products/28/variations";

    fetch(productsURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          products: response
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let lengthVariations = this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <LengthSelectorButtons lengths={product.option} />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        <div className="mainRightContainer">
          <h1 className="hairTitle">{this.props.hairPatternName}</h1>
          <p className="subTitles">{this.props.hairTextureName}</p>
          <LaceSelectorButtons />
          <p style={{ paddingTop: "121.5px" }} className="subTitles">
            Lengths
          </p>
          {lengthVariations}
          <div className="cartButton">
            <h1 className="cartTitle">ADD TO CART</h1>
          </div>
          <ReviewsShopPage />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `products` state is an empty array initially, which is correct. Your `response` is therefor most likely not an array. Maybe you should write `response.someArrayValue` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tholle, my response has multiple objects in the array - I checked on postman. Kinda of confused am I missing something?

Comment: Alright. Yes, your `products` state is initially an empty array (`[]`) which has a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. It sounds like you after your `fetch` request then set the `products` to an object, which *doesn't* have a `map` method. Maybe you should just write `this.setState(response)`, if you have many things you would want in your state in the response?

Comment: Sorry  I do not follow, I'm kinda new to this. From my understanding this.setState is used to reassign props to things so I'm not understanding the `this.setState(response)` part of your answer. and the function this is in is a `componentDidMount()` so is this not called before `render()`, so how does `lengthVariations` not have the right things for `map()`?

Comment: That's alright. Your code looks correct, it's just that the value of `response` in `this.setState({ products: response })` is not an array. If you check in PostMan, it most likely looks like `{ products: [ ... ] }` or something similar. You must use the array in the `response` object, e.g. `this.setState({ products: response.products })` or whatever the name of the array in the `response` object is.

Comment: Oh I see, hmm in postman the json is like this `[ {}, {}, {},.....]` which is an array right? is my code rendering an error becuase I'm putting an array into an empty array?

Comment: If your `response` is just `[ {}, {}, {}, ...]` then the code you have in your question should work. Could you include your entire component? There might be something else that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Theolle I've edited to include the component

Comment: Thanks. It looks correct to me. Could you write `console.log(this.state.products);` at the start of your render method to see if it contains what you think? If not, it might be that your network request fails. You could try adding a `.catch(error => console.error(error))` at the end of your fetch. Since it works for you in postman, it might be that there is a CORS issue since you send the request to another origin `http://localhost:8888`.

Comment: I bet CORS will be the guilty person :)

Comment: Ahhh yes! I am getting a 401 error! In postman I had used authorisation type OAuth 1.0 and input my consumer key and consumer secret. I need to add this to my code. Thank you!